# if I add a parameter in a ERC721's mint function, is it still ERC721?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721

like this, I add a bool value in ERC721's _safeMint and _mint function
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Minting functions are (contrary to popular belief) not part of the ERC-721 standard.

See this specific text in the [specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#:%7E:text=Creation%20of%20NFTs%20(%E2%80%9Cminting%E2%80%9D)%20and%20destruction%20of%20NFTs%20(%E2%80%9Cburning%E2%80%9D)%20is%20not%20included%20in%20the%20specification.) -

> Creation of NFTs (“minting”) and destruction of NFTs (“burning”) is
> not included in the specification. Your contract may implement these
> by other means.

Comment: thank you，please give me a vote if it's convenient.